# File Structure Best Practices when Managing Cloud Hosts?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, vps

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS server with Digital Ocean. I connect as root user through ssh.

Upon connecting I land in the `root@cloudserver:~` home directory which is empty by default. To access anything else I need to `cd /` to root.

Where should I be downloading and installing packages (vagrant, ansible, apache, etc.)? In the root directory, the home directory? Should the home directory remain empty? Or is it as simple as "wherever you want".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cloud host server is no different than your local machine.

Download the applications (when needed) to local directories and the installation will know a default location, if you're not sure leave this default location. The same if you install app through package manager, they will know where to install app